# Retrieve count from a sql stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

If i do this sql query below I get the single value 26

```
    SELECT Count(*)

FROM [sqlPractice].[dbo].[vcVisitors]
```

But when i use the below stored procedure it has 2 results - the number I am after and then a return value which is '0'. How do i get the other value and input it into a label?
[image]

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[UP_SEL_Count]
(
@expectedDate as datetime
)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT Count(*)

FROM [sqlPractice].[dbo].[vcVisitors]
Where expectedDate = @expectedDate and cancelled = 0

END
GO
```

The code i use to inout the number into a label is below - but all it does is show the return value (0) - how do i get the value i want?

```
 int total_visits = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

  lblTotal_vis_today.Text = total_visits.ToString();
```

Comment: You have a condition in your stored procedure while your first query hasn't. Try to run that in sql query window, and see the result!

Comment: Your first example with no where clause, but in stored procedure you have 2 criteria in where clause. Are you sure that stored procedure works properly? Execute your stored procedure directly on the Sql Server. Or track your query by using Sql Profiler.

Comment: I think you have an extra condition (cancelled = 0) which may be the culprit !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date value being sent to @expectedDate wasn't correct so I wasn't getting the values I needed back. All fixed now - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article on how to return values from a stored procedure: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx